# Admin aproval required even for basic microsoft graph permissions

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have small desktop app made with electron that needs to access the users calendar.

A personal account works just fine but with an organization account I need admin aproval even though I request non admin permissions.
This is permission config in the app:

```
scopes: [
  'user.read',
  'calendars.read'
],
```

In azure these don't require admin approval.
[image]
but when I login I get this message:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Admin consent required` column shows the default value for your organization.

However, user consent can be customized per permission and that's the reason why this column does not reflect the real value in your organization.

You have to ask your admin to grant the permissions.

[Configure user content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal)